# Vue axios method takes two clicks?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Trying to increment / decrement through json posts using vue but my methods are taking two clicks to fire? Should I not be using async await on the methods? I'm not sure what causes the event to not fire until second click?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Post :post="post"/>
    <button @click="prevPost()">Previous Post</button>
    <button @click="nextPost()">Next Post</button>
  </div>
</template>
    



  data () {
    return {
      apiUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
      page: 1,
      post: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    postUrl (): string {
      return `${this.apiUrl}${this.page}`
    }
  },
  async created () {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(this.postUrl)
      this.post = data
      console.log(this.post)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async prevPost () {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}` + this.page--)
        this.post = data
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
    async nextPost () {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}` + this.page++)
        this.post = data
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're incrementing and decrementing `this.page` after using it (**this.page++, this.page--**), not before, hence the need to click two times.

just do it before, and it works with one click:

```
// in prevPost
const { data } = await axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}` + --this.page)

// in nextPost 
const { data } = await axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}` + ++this.page)
```

Also, not part of your question, but look out for negative indices, check them.